# Why don't change lvm directory name under in etc directory

Tags: centos

Now I have met strange problem in Linux Centos 7.

I would like to test "recreate the device files for LVM volumes". In this case, you can be system crash and lost devices file for lVM. For that, I deleted any volume group device file under /dev/mapper/ directory. And I wanted to rename lvm directory name under /etc directory in which I want to observe again create this directory or no when I wrote "vgmknodes" commands. In this time It gave me Permission denied that I was in system with root user.

## mv /etc/lvm /etc/lvm.old

mv: cannot move ‘/etc/lvm’ to ‘/etc/lvm.old’: Permission denied

What is reason? Why permission denied via root user

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to test that. Those device files are created dynamically as the system runs; typically by udev.

Go to `/etc/udev/rules.d` and you'll probably see a file named something like `11-dm-lvm.rules`. That file is used by udev to create device files such as */dev/VG/LV*.

Even better, boot another Linux system and then mount, root filesystem somewhere (such as /mnt) and take a look at it's /dev. It will have very few files in it, if anything at all.